# Does NEVPNManager support L2TP now?

Tags: ios, networkextension, nevpnmanager

I've seen older post about Apple not supporting L2TP through `NEVPNManager`. I was really hoping by now something has changed, but I'm not finding much on the matter. Is there a way yet to use `NEVPNManager` with L2TP?

Comment: Hello any updates ? NEVPNManager connects L2TP ?

Comment: I got it working by just using it as IPSec

Comment: Same problem I post a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53781609/nevpnmanager-with-l2tp-protocol)

Answer (score 0):

No, you need use SCNetwork and Helper Tool (to get root access)
With this link you will be able to create L2TP Protocol and connect with it